# Python - Removing multiline comments from a list

Tags: python

I have a list of data:

```
data = ['value', '"""', 'Comment 1st row', 'Comment 2nd row', 'Comment 3rd row', '"""', 'another value']
```

I would like to remove the whole comment from the list, including docstrings. Also not just once, but everytime a comment appears.

Could someone help?

Comment: what's the data characteristics: array of strings? How are the string comments different to the value ones? what do they contain in particular?

Comment: It means you want to remove all items that appear between `'"""`?
'"""', 'Comment 1st row', 'Comment 2nd row', 'Comment 3rd row', '"""'

Comment: Everything in a list is a string. Yes I want to remove everything between """ including.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple loop with a flag that alternates every time a `"""` is found:

```
data = ['value', '"""', 'Comment 1st row', 'Comment 2nd row',
        'Comment 3rd row', '"""', 'another value']

flag = True
out = []
for v in data:
    if v == '"""':
        flag = not flag  # invert the flag's boolean value
        continue         # we have a comment, skip to the next step
    if flag:             # if flag is True, add the item
        out.append(v)

print(out)
```

output:

```
['value', 'another value']
```

Example run on `data = data * 5` to mimic multiple comments:

```
['value', 'another value', 'value', 'another value',
 'value', 'another value', 'value', 'another value',
 'value', 'another value']
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working on it's own (I will try to implement it in the more complex function). I'm just learning, could you explain to me what does flag = not flag do? Is it the same as flag = False? Thanks

Comment: No, this is inverting the boolean value of `flag` (`True`->`False` / `False` -> `True`)

Comment: Awesome I went through it line-by-line to understand the logic and I kind of get it now. Cool stuff, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = ['value', '"""', 'Comment 1st row', 'Comment 2nd row', 'Comment 3rd row', '"""', 'another value']

newData = []

comment = False

for word in data:
    if word == '"""':
        comment = not comment
    elif not comment:
        newData.append(word)

print(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `re`,

```
import re
sp_chr = '$'
list(filter(None, re.sub(r'""".*"""', '', sp_chr.join(data)).split(sp_chr)))
```

Output:

```
['value', 'another value']
```

`$` is a unique character used to separate the elements in the list. You have the freedom to choose any values there.

Comment: A built-in version `list(filter(None, ''.join('$'.join(data).split('"""')[::2]).split('$')))`

Answer (score 0):

A counter-based approach. If the amount of `"""` is even then append (comments are balanced), instead increment the counter if odd (since comment hasn't finished).

```
res = []
c = 0
for char in data:
    if char != '"""':
        if not c % 2:
            res.append(char)
    else:
        c += 1

print(res)
```